# Trouble with Floating

Tags: haskell

Apologies if this problem is really straight-forward, but I've been messing a bit with a random piece of code I made and I'm curious why the following won't compile:

```
test::Floating a => Int -> [a]
test x = map(\y -> (y * abs(cos(y)))) [0..x]
```

I'm trying to understand most typeclasses and I thought of using Floating since we're using cosine. The goal of the function is to make a list of 0 to x with the following function: `\y -> (y * abs(cos(y)))`

However the compiler complains about the type of x ("Couldn't match type 'a' with 'Int'"), saying it expects a type [a] but receives [Int].
Why is this? After all I'm feeding those integers to my anonymous function to get a list of Floats.

Comment: since `x` is an `Int`, that means `[0..x]` is a list of `Int`s, and therefore `y` is also an `Int`, since all functions like `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` require the two operands and the result to be the same type, this will thus not work.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since `x` is an `Int`, that means `[0..x]` is a list of `Int`s, and therefore `y` is also an `Int`, since all functions like `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` require the two operands and the result to be the same type, this will thus not work.

You can however make use of [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert a number of the `Integral` type to any `Num` type:

```
test :: Floating a => Int -> [a]
test x = map(\y -> let yf = fromIntegral y in yf * abs (cos yf)) [0..x]
```